# The app should add a new row in the database, but it stops working

Tags: android, database

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this code? It should add a new row in the database, but when I run it, the app stops. I checked and the contact's details are created ok, but when it comes to add the new information in the db, it just stops working.

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ContactsDetails.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ConactsDetails";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
            COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add new contact's details
public void addContact(NewUserContacts contact){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, contact.getFirstName());
    values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, contact.getSurname());
    values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, contact.getDescription());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, contact.getUsername());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, contact.getPassword());

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: what is it showing in logcat? error message?

Comment: hundreds of possible reasons, without seeing the error stack, we can´t help, so please post it here...

Comment: And what is "contact details"? Is this the database name? I don´t think that any table could be created because you made an error in your create String. `" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"` you forget comma , also after every `" TEXT"` ...should be `" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "` and `" TEXT,"`